# Is Django 3.0 compatible with Jinja2 when rendering forms?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I am using Jinja2 (via django-jinja 2.3.1) in my Django 3.0 project.

It renders the templates fine, however when I want to display a `{{ form }}` such as in a `LoginView` I get the following error:

> expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'

I traced this back to the input widget in `django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/input.html`, which renders as follows:

```
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}"
{% if widget.value != None %} value="{{ widget.value|stringformat:'s' }}"
{% endif %}{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
```

It would appear Jinja doesn't accept `|stringformat:'s'`, is this correct? Does this mean it is not compatible with Django forms? Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: The syntaxes of Django and Jinja forms are similar but not the same. As a result you can't render Django templates with Jinja2.

Comment: No, because when you `{% include %}` another template in a jinja2 template, the included template is also assumed to be a jinja2 template. So you can't use Django's built-in widgets as they need the Django template rendering engine. You can create your own widgets though by copying the django widgets and fixing them to work for jinja2 (e.g. `{{ "%s" % widget.value }}` would be the jinja2 equivalent) and define your widget classes to just subclass the Django ones and use your templates instead.